# Dark Souls 3 Fire Fades Edition for Steam

Tags: steam, version-differences, dark-souls-3

Is Dark Souls 3: The Fire Fades edition only a deluxe edition of the original game with no additional content ? I've recently bought a game for steam and I noticed that it doesn't contain any subtitle ("Fire Fades") in the subtitle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically the normal game + all DLC.

Comment: This sums it up.  Link for reference: http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Dark+Souls+3+The+Fire+Fades+Edition